# tflearn learning_rate summary

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Learning rate is automatically added to the summary collections for SGD and Momentum.
However they are not added to the summary. What is the fastest and easiest way to fetch this key and visualize on the TensorBoard?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `merge_all_summaries`, then all summaries from the `GraphKeys.SUMMARIES` are included. An example of doing it is in [models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py)

```
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph)
summary_str = sess.run(summary_op)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
```

Comment: I am not using pure tensorflow and all this is done by TFLearn and appearantly they dont add it automatically. Can I add it after the session is created?